# Checking if the optional list is valid in java

Tags: java, java-8

Let's say I have a list of users. `List<User> users`;

```
class User{
 private String userId;
 //getters setters.
}
```

I wanted to check, whether the list is valid or not. List is not valid if below condition is matched.

1. It's empty
   OR
2. If User in each of the list items have userId value.

How can I do that using `java.utils.Optional` in a cleaner way?

Comment: can you rephrase the requirement(using some code) and confirm if the *List is not valid...If User in each of the list items have userId value.* si what you actually meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional is completely irrelevant.

Just check if all the users have a userId:

```
boolean valid = users.stream().allMatch(u -> u.getUserId() != null);
```

Comment: *List is not valid ...If User in each of the list items have userId value* ...strange but weird requirement in the question